# objective c sort and create different arrays on the bases of string year

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a situation where i have an array of custom objects, and each object contains a string property name "year", which will contain years entered by user in a text field, like 2012, 2013 etc (it can be any year). now i have to sort that array on the bases of that year in such a way that sort objects of 2012 year in another array or data structure, 2013 in another data structure, like this

```
2012 =     (
        "<CustomObject: 0xc164250>",
        "<CustomObject: 0xc33d910>",
        "<CustomObject: 0xc33cfb0>",
        "<CustomObject: 0xc3204c0>"
    );
    2013 =     (
        "<CustomObject: 0xc1a9d20>",
        "<CustomObject: 0xc43af80>",
        "<CustomObject: 0xc43f830>",
        "<CustomObject: 0xb4a1ea0>",
        "<CustomObject: 0xb48caa0>"
    );
    2014 =     (
        "<CustomObject: 0xc16ee40>"
    );
}
```

how can i do this plz. guide.

Comment: You can get the distinct values of years from all of your custom objects and then use predicates to filter that array according to 'year'.

Answer (score 2):

`NSMutableDictionary * groupedByYear = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *object; // An array of your objects that needs to be sorted

[object enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSMutableArray *objectsForYear = groupedByYear[obj.year];
    if (!objectsForYear) {
        objectsForYear = [NSMutableArray array];
        groupedByYear[obj.year] = objectsForYear;
    }
    [objectsForYear addObject:obj];
}];`

Answer (score 0):

Just my idea:

```
NSArray *customObjects; // contains array Custom Objects
NSMutableArray *years= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableArray new]/*2002*/,[NSMutableArray new]/*2003*/,[NSMutableArray new]/*2004*/, nil];
for(CustomObject *obj in customObjects){
  if(obj.year.intValue == 2002)      {[years[0] addObject:obj];}
  else if(obj.year.intValue == 2003) {[years[1] addObject:obj];}
  else                               {[years[2] addObject:obj];}
}
```

Waiting for better solution